# mongodb - get only the keys from a document

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection as follows -

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("..."),
    "k1" : v11,
    "f1" : {
        "k2" : "v2",
        "k3" : "v3",
        "k4" : "v4",
    }

}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("..."),
    "k1" : v12,
    "f1" : {
        "k5" : "v5",
        "k6" : "v6",
        "k7" : "v7",
    }

}
```

I need to loop thru' f1, and get only the keys such as k2, k3, k4, and then append this with the value from k1. ie. I need something like `v11+k2, v11+k3, v11+v4,` etc. How can I go about achieving this? I don't have a clue where to start.

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible through Map-Reduce. The following mapreduce operation will populate a separate collection called `collectionNameKeys` with all the keys as the _id values:

```
mr = db.runCommand({
    "mapreduce": "collectionName",
    "map" : function() {
        for (var key in this.f1) { emit(this.k1+key, null); }
    },
    "reduce" : function() {}, 
    "out": "collectionNameKeys"
})
```

To get a list of all the concatenated keys, run distinct on the resulting collection:

```
db[mr.result].distinct("_id")
```

**Sample Output**

```
[ "v11k2", "v11k3", "v11k4", "v12k5", "v12k6", "v12k7" ]
```